# Adding shared folder to onedrive through terminal

Tags: ssh, 20.04

I have installed onedrive on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. Its running in monitor mode, syncing is working fine.
I would like to add a shared folder (onedrive folder that somebody else shared with me). on my local machine i do this by going to my online onedrive account, clicking sync folder and opening the link with onedrive.

With this computer I am accessing the machine through ssh, so I am left with terminal commands only https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/onedrive.1.html. I am a little confused which command should I use for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to add a shared folder (onedrive folder that somebody else shared with me).

What account type are you using? Personal? Business/Office365?

If Personal, you add the 'shared folder' using the OneDrive web interface, by using the add to my OneDrive, then the 'shared folder' will automatically sync without further configuration.

If you are syncing a Business/Office365 shared folder, you need to configure this functionality as per https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/BusinessSharedFolders.md

As you are also running Ubuntu, make sure you are using either the Ubuntu PPA or building the client from source. Simply installing via 'apt install onedrive' will install an older client version. Be sure to check your client version with 'onedrive --version' and compare this to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/releases. Latest release currently is v2.4.5 with v2.4.6 due by end of September 2020.